# Efficiency of looping though a text map to draw objects

Tags: javascript, optimization, game

I am making a game that uses a text map to draw obstacles and courses for the player to navigate. However, I am concerned that my method of looping through the text map to draw objects on the screen isn't as efficient as it could be.

View the [playable project on Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/platformer-example/6233408516128768).

Here is my code dealing with the text map:

```
var platforms = [];
platforms.add = function(xPosition, yPosition, width, height, colour) {
    platforms.push( new Block(xPosition, yPosition, width, height, colour) );
};

platforms.display = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
        platforms[i].display();
    }
};
var levelOne = [
    // each symbol is equivalent to 40 pixels
    ["##########"], // # - block
    ["#        #"], // S - starting position
    ["#        #"],
    ["#        #"],
    ["#        #"],
    ["#  #     #"],
    ["#       ##"],
    ["#     #  #"],
    ["#S  #    #"],
    ["##########"],
];
var symbol;
var playerX;
var playerY;
for(var i = 0; i < levelOne.length; i++) {

    for(var j = 0; j < levelOne[i].length; j++) {
        for(var v = 0; v < levelOne[i][j].length; v++) {
            var symbol = levelOne[i][j][v];
            if(symbol === "#") {
            // Platform arguments: X, Y, Width, Height, Color
                platforms.add(v*width/10, i*height/10, width/10, height/10, color(0, 174, 255));
            } else if (symbol === "S") {
                playerX = v*width/10;
                playerY = i*height/10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make this code more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for starters, you could reduce operations to \$O(n^2)\$ by skipping your third loop:

```
var levels = [
    ["##########",
     "#        #",
     "#        #",
     "#        #",
     "#        #",
     "#  #     #",
     "#       ##",
     "#     #  #",
     "#S  #    #",
     "##########"]
];

for(var i = 0; i < levels[0].length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < levels[0][i].length; j++){
        var symbol = levels[0][i][j];
        console.log(symbol);
    }
}
```

I changed `levelOne` to a `levels` array where you can refer to each level by index, since you probably want to add more levels later on.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4jc98Lq/1/)

Why do you define `symbol` outside of the loop, and re-declare it inside?

Regarding your `platforms`:

```
var platforms = [];

platforms.add = function(xPosition, yPosition, width, height, colour) {
    platforms.push(new Block(xPosition, yPosition, width, height, colour) );
};
```

You are just declaring an `add` method for that specific array instance. It also creates an enumerable property on the array which isn't good if someone happens to use `for..in` to iterate the array (which I wouldn't recommend in the first place). Why not simply call `push` directly?

If you insist on creating your own `add` method, in my opinion, `platforms` should be either its own "type" (if you plan to create several instances):

```
function platform(){
    this.blocks = [];
}

platform.prototype.addBlock(function(block){
    this.blocks.push(block);
});
```

Or if you know that you'll only use one platform, create a "static" object:

```
var platform = {
    blocks: [],
    addBlock: function(block){
        this.blocks.push(block);
    }
};
```